# No-Connection remote MySQL Connection With JPA EclipseLink

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am working on a desktop app with JPA(Eclipselink) and a remote mysql database directly.

My persistence.xml i have two PersistenceUnit one uses localhost the other uses my remote database. When i try to load EntityManagerFactory, it works fine on localhost but never gets connected to the remote and no error is provided just a very long wait. Here is part of my persistence.xml

REMOTE MYSQL ON Windows Server 2003.

```
<persistence-unit name="SOFALEnterprisePU3" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.138:3306/sofaldb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
</properties>
```

LOCAL MYSQL

```
<persistence-unit name="SOFALEnterprisePU2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sofaldb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say remote do you mean the same LAN or accross the internet? Cause the IP 192.168.10.138 designates a private LAN so your remote machine has to have an address on the same network like 192.168.10.*

First make sure to open port 3306 in your windows firewall.

If it is a different network, your router(s) will need to be configured to forward the port and you will have to connect to the public IP of the router.

If it is the same LAN then mysql might not have been setup to accept remote connections for that user name password combination.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Everything is on the local network. Do you have any idea of the performance based on the fact that i'm using a swing application that connects to the db directly via JPA.

Comment: Never used JPA from a rich client, only from Java EE. I think it depends on how many concurrent users you will have. If you have many clients at the same time especially when you also have them access the DB over the internet you might be better of letting your clients talk to a Java EE webservice and let that service talk to the DB using JPA.

Answer (score 0):

In normal JPA, it uses only one persistence.xml per project.But you can try [Spring's JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa) that can use multiple persistence.xml in one project.See this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-multiple-pu) to deal with multiple persistence units.

Comment: I am using the different persistenceUnits for different purposes, when i'm ready to deploy with the remote mysql i just change to the one i want to use!